# I need a download image function to support multiple browers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, download, safari

I have a function that works beautifully in Chrome. The user checks multiple photos and can download them to their computer. Photos are saved in the download folder. These photos are being pulled from my amazonS3 account.

However, in Safari and Firefox, when the user hits the download button it displays the first image in the array in the browser window. No download happens.

Is there a way to modify my code to support Safari and Firefox as well? I need the photos to save in the Downloads folder on the desktop.
Im using AngularJS.

The first function goes through the checked photos and puts them in an array.
The second function downloads the photos.

Code below:

```
$scope.downloadPhotos = function() {
    var photoUrls = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < $scope.$parent.photos.length; x++) {

        var p = $scope.$parent.photos[x];
        if (p.isChecked) {
            photoUrls.push($scope.bucketUrl() + p.photoUrl);

        }
    }

    saveImage(photoUrls);
};

function saveImage(urls) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');

    link.setAttribute('download', null);
    link.style.display = 'none';

    document.body.appendChild(link);

    for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
        link.setAttribute('href', urls[i]);
        link.click();
    }

    document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

Comment: `If this attribute is present and Content-Disposition: is set to inline, Firefox gives priority to Content-Disposition, like for the filename case, while Chrome gives priority to the download attribute.`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: Wait, seriously? You can click links for me that download things? Who thought this was a good idea?

Comment: @AlexVanLiew Only if still within a click event handler. So, you click, and then i can click other things for you.

Comment: I guess I need to stop clicking things on the internet.

Comment: Im not clicking links. My downloadPhotos button grabs the image urls from amazonS3, (which are determined by the images i checked that get stored in my array). They download just fine in chrome. But in safari and firefox it just opens the first image in array in browser window. Does my question make sense? I just need this perfectly working function to work in firefox and safari.